# Windows controlled folder access to secure Chrome cookies?

Tags: vulnerability, account-security, multi-factor, u2f, fido

I've read about Linus Tech Tips hack, where a malware stole the browser cookies & was able to log in to Linus's channel.

Is this preventable with Windows controlled folder access (preventing apps other than Chrome from accessing the cookie files)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Permissions are granted to users, not to applications. If user is running some infected application, this application can access any file where access to this user is granted.

Only if malware is running under account other than the current user and doesn't have admin privileges, it will not be able to access the files of the current user.

But some antiviruses offer folder and file based access control for applications.

Windows has deep integration with antivirus software, so that now it is hard to distinguish if **controlled folder access** is an antivirus functionality or rather Windows functionality. See the [Microsoft documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/allow-an-app-to-access-controlled-folders-b5b6627a-b008-2ca2-7931-7e51e912b034) about this.

Answer (score 0):

Even if it were possible to prevent naive non-Chrome apps from accessing a given file or directory, it's not possible to prevent competent ones. You might break existing malware, but if such "protection" became common, malware would just be re-written to either use binary replacement (Chrome by default installs in a user-writable location), DLL injection, direct debugger takeover, or Windows Automation/Accessibility functionality to either force Chrome to exfiltrate its secrets, or wear Chrome as a skin and go get the files itself.

Once malware is running within your account (and not severely sandboxed), it's game over. You'd get more mileage out of sandboxing everything than out of trying to work around the Windows (and Linux, and even MacOS) security model like this; it just isn't worth it.

Comment: I'm no security expert, but I thought that Windows Controlled Folder access was effective at blocking apps from accessing sensitive data, is it easy to bypass?

Also, how would you go about sandboxing everything in windows?

Thanks

Comment: I haven't looked into the details of it much, but it sure looks easy to bypass. Still useful against the run-of-the-mill low-effort (or legacy) malware, but not very effective against a targeted attack or anything modern written by somebody competent. I could be wrong though. As for sandboxing... there's no really good option. All the major browsers are sandboxed, as are many Windows Store apps, but beyond that most things on Windows aren't sandboxed by default and it's hard to stuff them into one and harder to have it work successfully afterward.

Comment: it would make those folders more secure... but you'd probably also want to protect Chrome itself.  An easy workaround would be for malware to modify Chrome itself... or add an extension/plugin and use that.  Windows already protects program files dirs, but if you run a bad executable and either bypass or accept Windows UAC prompts, all bets are off.  It's always security vs. convenience.  Easiest solution is to not run untrusted executables.   You're already one-up on Linus, btw, cause he was running Linux where the password db in Chrome is much less secure.